# Android data_roaming and bluetooth_on exception

Tags: android

On Android, I've been trying to retrieve data_roaming and bluetooth_on to see if they are enabled.

I've used the following:

```
Cursor cursorCheck = getContentResolver().query(
                Settings.Global.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{Settings.Global.BLUETOOTH_ON},
                null, null, null);
        assert cursorCheck != null;
        cursorCheck.moveToFirst();
        for (int i = 0; i < cursorCheck.getCount(); i++) {
            Log.i("check1", cursorCheck.getString(0) + " ");
            cursorCheck.moveToNext();
        }
        cursorCheck.close();
```

However, I get the following exception:

"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column: bluetooth_on" / "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column: data_roaming"

URLs:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#BLUETOOTH_ON
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#DATA_ROAMING

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that `Settings.Global.BLUETOOTH_ON` is not the name of column , the name of column is `name` , `bluetooth_on` is the value inside that column so when you make a query write like this :

```
 Cursor cursorCheck = getContentResolver().query(
                Settings.Global.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
               "name=?", new String[]{"bluetooth_on"}, null);
```

this searchs name column with `bluetooth_on` value and gets you the result.

For multiple add `or` like this `name=? or name=?` and add values you like to get to the string array.

To get bluetooth on off state use :

```
cursorCheck.getString(2)
```

enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, but I get values that are not 0 or 1, I get numbers like for example 29, what does that mean?

Comment: Try changing `cursorCheck.getString(0)` to other values eg 1,2 maybe you will get

Comment: @EliorCohen use cursorCheck.getString(2) this will give you correct

Comment: Thanks, but "name=? or name=?" not works, why? I get: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Supported SQL:
      uri content://some_table/some_property with null where and where args
      uri content://some_table with query name=? and single name as arg
      uri content://some_table with query name=some_name and null args
      but got - uri:content://settings/global, where:name=? or name=? whereArgs:[data_roaming, bluetooth_on]

Comment: Use it when you need to get two values

Comment: I use that because that what I need, 2 values

Comment: @EliorCohen try to check the actual name of the fields in cursor , in my case there was no data_roaming but there was data_roaming1 , data_roaming2 , etc try to check the names from cursor